# showing part of theme only if has variable

Tags: php, html, hide

I need to know how to hide a part of template if no have variable,

here is my code that i need to be hide before i give it variable:

```
<div class="row">
   <!--forum-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Latest forum topics</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
      if(is_active_sidebar('forum')){
      dynamic_sidebar('forum');
      }
      ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- end of forum-->
  <!--slider-->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Popular posts</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of slider -->    
</div>
```

Right now for example `forum` part is like what i want but only the content, i need to forum box be the same too.

Can you tell me how to do it?
totally i need to learn this thing for other parts i no want just copy and paste the code, if you could explain to me i'll be grateful .

Thanks of **emmanuel** for solve my issue,

**UPDATE:**

Now the second part of my codes is changed to this:

```
  <!--slider-->
  <?php if (function_exists('do_shortcode')): ?>
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Popular posts</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[cycloneslider id ="slider"]'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- end of slider -->
```

and everything works fine but the issue is if even my variable is empty will show the box and also some note.

ps: that some note i can remove it by edit plugin (No Problem) but the problem is showing that box, i want only if have variable shows box+slide if not not show anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the part you want to show / hide in an if ... endif condition.

```
<?php if(is_active_sidebar('forum')) : ?>
<!--forum-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Latest forum topics</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- end of forum-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)